# Elasticsearch aggregation by full array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How i can to get aggregation by all array items inside document, not by each value of array. For example i have several documents, like this

```
{'some_field': [1,2]}
{'some_field': [1]}
{'some_field': [1]}
{'some_field': [7,2]}
```

Now with simple aggregation query like this

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "agg_name" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "some_field"
        }
    }
},
"size": 0
}
```

i got result like this

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        ...
]
```

but i want to get full array view, like this

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": [1],
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": [1,2],
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": [7,2],
          "doc_count": 1
        },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same aggregation, still doesn't exists.
So fixed with a painless script

```
POST some_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myaggs": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 100,
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            def myString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < doc['data. some_field.keyword'].length; ++i) {
              myString += doc['data. some_field.keyword'][i] + ", ";
            }
            return myString;
          """
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```